# Problema ao acessar métodos da classe concreta usando referencia this em C#

Tags: c#, genéricos

Implementei uma classe `Service` abstrata usando `Generics` e outra usando `EmpresaService` sendo concreta.

Toda estrutura do projeto para cada classe concreta tem uma abstrata.

Minha dúvida vendo do seguinte...

Ao utilizar a referencia `this.Dao.ExisteRegistro();`, ele aponta pra o método na classe abstrata e não na concreta, e isso fica ruim pois complica na hora de implementar métodos individuais na classe `EmpresaDao` por exemplo.

Meu erro esta sendo no projeto de classes?

Classe PlanoService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Cobranca.pkgDao;
using Cobranca.pkgModel;

namespace Cobranca.pkgService
{
    public class PlanoService : Service<Plano>
    {

        public PlanoService()
        {
            this.Dao = new PlanoDao();
        }

        //método em questão que mostra o erro
        public bool ExisteRegistro()
        {
            return this.Dao.ExisteRegistro();
        }

        // métodos e mais métodos abaixo
    }
}
```

Classe EmpresaDao

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Cobranca.pkgModel;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Cobranca.pkgDao
{
    class EmpresaDao : Dao<Empresa>
    {
        public bool ExistePlanos()
        {
            try
            {
                base.AbrirConexao();
                MySqlCommand cmd = base.Conexao.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planos";
                return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.FecharConexao();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Dao

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Cobranca.pkgModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Cobranca.pkgDao
{

    public abstract class Dao<TModel> where TModel : Persistant
    {
        public abstract bool Inserir(TModel model);
        public abstract bool Editar(TModel model);
        public abstract bool Excluir(long codigo);

        public abstract List<TModel> CarregarDados();

    }
}


Classe PlanoDao

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Cobranca.pkgModel;

namespace Cobranca.pkgDao
{
    public class PlanoDao : Dao<Plano>
    {
        public bool ExisteRegistro()
        {
            try
            {
                base.AbrirConexao();
                MySqlCommand cmd = base.Conexao.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM planos";
                return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.FecharConexao();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar os códigos completos, pois, os seus exemplos são estão nos códigos informados. O método `this.Dao.ExisteRegistro();` está chamando `PlanoDao` e não `EmpresaDao`. Já `EmpresaDao` não tem o méotod `ExisteRegistro`.

Comment: Não adicionei a classe inteira para não poluir o código, mas adicionei parte da classe `PlanoDao`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Ao utilizar a referencia this.Dao.ExisteRegistro();, ele aponta pra o método na classe abstrata"*

A palavra reservada `this` sempre referencia a classe atual, para referenciar a classe a qual está estendendo, é usado `base`.

Da documentação do MSDN:

> A palavra-chave this refere-se à instância atual da classe e também é
>   usada como um modificador do primeiro parâmetro de um método de
>   extensão.

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this

Para demonstrar isso, fiz um pequeno bloco de código:

```
public abstract class ClasseAbstrata
{
    public abstract bool Inserir(int x);
    public abstract bool Editar(int x);
    public abstract bool Excluir(int x);

    public string QuemSouEu()
    {
        return "Abstrata";
    }
}

public class Derivada : ClasseAbstrata
{
    public override bool  Inserir(int x) { return false; }
    public override bool Editar(int x) { return false; }
    public override bool Excluir(int x) { return false; }

    public string QuemSouEu()
    {
        return "Derivada";
    }

    public string QuemSouEuBase()
    {
        return base.QuemSouEu();
    }
    public string QuemSouEuThis()
    {
        return this.QuemSouEu();
    }
    public string QuemSouEuParseAbstrata()
    {
        return ((ClasseAbstrata)this).QuemSouEu();
    }
    public string QuemSouEuParseDerivada()
    {
        return ((Derivada)this).QuemSouEu();
    }
}
```

Peguei o exemplo da classe acima, e adicionei um método na classe abstrata: `QuemSouEu()`.  Como os demais métodos são abstratos e não implementação na classe abastrata, `this` não terá efeito prático aqui, então vamos ver como se comporta o método `QuemSouEu` usando esse código:

```
var d = new Derivada();
Console.WriteLine("QuemSouEu: " + d.QuemSouEu());
Console.WriteLine("QuemSouEuBase: " + d.QuemSouEuBase());
Console.WriteLine("QuemSouEuThis: " + d.QuemSouEuThis());
Console.WriteLine("QuemSouEuParseAbstrata: " + d.QuemSouEuParseAbstrata());
Console.WriteLine("QuemSouEuParseDerivada: " + d.QuemSouEuParseDerivada());
```

Resultados:

> QuemSouEu: Derivada
>   QuemSouEuBase: Abstrata
>   QuemSouEuThis: Derivada
>   QuemSouEuParseAbstrata: Abstrata
>   QuemSouEuParseDerivada: Derivada

Podemos notar que onde foi usado `this` (QuemSouEuThis) retornou a partir da classe derivada, e não da abstrata, mesmo sobrescrevendo o método.

Outros observações:
- `base` referencia a classe abstrata;
- é possível fazer `cast` para qualquer das classes para ter o resultado esperado (métodos QuemSouEuParseAbstrata e  QuemSouEuParseDerivada)

Aqui o fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mc7u2E